# Wordpress next_posts_link() only reloads the same page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a problem with my Wordpress theme. My `next_posts_link()` only reloads the same page. Here's my code.

```
    <div id="main">

    <?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="utdrag">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <div class="crop"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php 
    if ( get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id) != '' ) {

    echo '<a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '" class="thumbnail-wrapper">';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    echo '</a>';

    } else {


    echo '<img src="';
     echo catch_that_image();
    echo '" alt="Image unavailable" class="crop" />';
     echo '</a>';

    }

    ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
    <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>

    <?php next_posts_link();?><?php previous_posts_link();?>


</div>
```

I'm using a static page as my front page. As you can see it's only displaying posts that have the same category as the page title: `query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');`

This is something I want to keep. So does anyone know why it just reloads? Why it isn't changing to the next page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! I'm posting it here in case someone else is having the same problem!

I added this code at the top:

```
<?php if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
     $paged = get_query_var('paged'); 
     }
    elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { 
    $paged = get_query_var('page'); 
    }
    else { $paged = 1; }
?>
```

And replaced this:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');?>
```

with this:

```
<?php query_posts('catery_name='.get_the_title().'&showposts=2'.'&paged='.$paged); ?>
```

For more information, check out this link: 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/front-page-wp-query-pagination-issue-repeating-posts-next_posts_link-help

Answer (score 1):

These two functions does not work on static pages.

From the documentation for [`wp_next_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link):

> This function does not work with static pages.

However, take a look at [this](http://moshublog.com/2007/09/10/static-frontpage-combined-with-dynamic-content/) article. It talks about how to create a static front page with dynamic content.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. Do you know if there is a way around it or? The article just summarized what I've already done.

Comment: @HåvardBrynjulfsen: You could try something like this: `<?php global $paged;
query_posts('paged='.$paged);
?>` but I'm not sure it will work.